# Cucumber ParameterType not recognized by IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I've registered a parameter:

```
@ParameterType(value = "Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday", name = "weekday")
    public WebElement weekday(String weekendDay) {
        switch (weekendDay) {
            case "Monday":
                return driver().findElement(By.className("sel-btn-weekday0"));
            case "Tuesday":
                return driver().findElement(By.className("sel-btn-weekday1"));
            case "Friday":
                return driver().findElement(By.className("sel-btn-weekday4"));
            case "Saturday":
                return driver().findElement(By.className("sel-btn-weekday5"));
            case "Sunday":
                return driver().findElement(By.className("sel-btn-weekday6"));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I have a step: 'When add Saturday, Sunday as Weekend'

and then have a method  annotated:
`@When("add {weekday}, {weekday} as weekend")`

When I run this with Cucumber plugin I got the error (shown below), but when I use gradle task to launch test via JUnit it passes. What can be the reason?

SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not create a cucumber expression for 'add {weekday}, {weekday} as Weekend'.
It appears you did not register a parameter type.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Have you specified the "glue" in IDE Cucumber Run configuration? Try also removing parameter name from the annotation.